# Why Does Android Studio Insist That I'm Using Android 4?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an Android project which I share with the rest of my team.  The project builds perfectly on the command line.  When I am viewing a particular source file in Android Studio, this line is red-highlighted as an error:

`mAccountSpinner = mView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker);`

Hovering over the error line, Android Studio says:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: com.mycompany.AccountPickerView
Found: android.view.View
```

My colleagues do not see this error. When I Ctrl-click on `findViewById`, Android Studio brings me to a cached Android 4 source: `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.android/4.1.1.4/.../View.java` !  This is the source of the error, because the Android 4 version of this function reads:

`public final  android.view.View findViewById(int id)`

When my colleagues do this, they are directed to a modern version of `findViewById` :

`public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id)`

Our project targets API 28.

I've tried Invalidate caches and restart. I've deleted my `~/.gradle` folder. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio.

Any suggestions as to what I've got wrong here?

Comment: can you post the `app/build.gradle`file?

Comment: Hi @nandsito, unfortunately I cannot. But note that my colleagues are all using the exact same `build.gradle` that I am, and not seeing this error.

Comment: I should have mentioned that our team includes people building on Macs and on Windows machines; I am currently using Windows. Also, although the line is red-highlighted by Android Studio, AS will build and deploy the APK to an emulator or a hardware device, which is also weird (like, shouldn't an error keep the compile from completing?).

Comment: unfortunately we are short of means to find out what the problem is... is your SDK up to date?

Comment: Yes, I wish I could give you more information, but I can tell you that my Android SDK is updated to API 28.

Comment: The SDK isn't always enough: did you check the module settings? AS does some weird stuff some times...

Answer (score 0):

I think if you cast your variable to AccountPickerView you should probably be able to get rid of this error.

```
mAccountSpinner = (AccountPickerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker);
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, and it will compile, but the point is I shouldn't have to do this, and it means that there is some way that I am out of sync with my colleagues. In the future, the consequences of that will be more severe. I would like to solve this problem while the issues it raises are small.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickBrennan. Sorry not sure why you're getting this error and how to fix it other than by avoiding it from happening through casting. Hope someone else may be better able to help you on that better than me.